# Python string either fraction or float to float

Tags: python, floating-point, fractions

I have a problem where I want to take a string which could say either a fraction like '1/6' or a float '2.0', and have them both evaluate to a final float value. What I don't know how to do is deal with the potential for either case to come up or how process them so I get the float output of the fraction.

```
numberArray = []
d1 = 0
d2 = 0

fileInput = f.readlines()

for line in fileInput:
    numberArray.append(line)

for i in numberArray:
    content = i.replace("\n","").split(" ")

    d1 = (float(content[0]))
    //The rest of data in the line is stored below (d2, d3 etc), but this isn't 
    // important. The important part is the first item that comes up in each line, 
    //and whether or not it is a fraction or already a float.
```

Input:

```
1/3 ...(rest of the line, not important)
2.0 ...
```

Output:

```
d1 (line1, item1) = 0.33
d2 (line1, item2) = ...

d1 (line2, item1) = 2.0
d2 (line2, item2) = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to python so this may not be the most elegant solution, but maybe something like:

```
import re

values = ["3.444", "3", "1/3", "1/5"]

def to_float(str):
    is_frac = bool(re.search("/", str))
    if is_frac:
        num_den = str.split("/")
        return float(num_den[0]) / float(num_den[1])
    else:
        return float(str)

floats = [to_float(i) for i in values]
print(floats)
```

Comment: There is no need for `re` here at all. Just test `if '/' in str:` instead of `is_frac = bool(re.search('/', str))` and `if is_frac:`

Answer (score 1):

[The `fractions.Fraction` constructor already knows how to parse both `float`-like strings and fraction-like strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction), and produce a `Fraction` result. For example:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> float(Fraction('1/3'))
0.3333333333333333
>>> float(Fraction('2.0'))
2.0
```

Since `Fraction` can be converted to `float`, you can use this to unconditionally produce a `float` result:

```
from fractions import Fraction

for line in f:
    content = line.strip('\r\n').split(" ")

    d1 = float(Fraction(content[0]))
    # The rest of data in the line is stored below (d2, d3 etc), but this isn't 
    # important. The important part is the first item that comes up in each line, 
    # and whether or not it is a fraction or already a float.
```

I took the liberty of dramatically simplifying your code; `f.readlines()` would already return a `list`, so it's pointless to iterate it again to populate `numberArray`, and since you only seem to populate `numberArray` to iterate it once anyway, it's simpler to just iterate the file directly rather than making two pointless temporaries. If you really need the `list`, you just do:

```
numberArray = f.readlines()
for line in numberArray:
```

to load the `list` once and store it directly, rather than copying element by element.

Comment: This does look rather straight forward actually, not sure why I couldn't find that when trying to find a solution to this before asking a question. Thanks for this answer.